# How to change color for links (href text) in thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, thymeleaf

I have the below link(href) in Thymeleaf page.

```
<div class="product-preview-container"
    th:each="prodInfo : ${products}">
    <ul>
        <li>Product Code:  <span th:utext="${prodInfo.productCode}"></span></li>
        <li>Product Name:  <span th:utext="${prodInfo.productName}"></span></li>
        <li>Product Price: Rs <span th:utext="${prodInfo.productPrice}"></span></li>
        <li><a th:href="@{|/shopping/buyProduct?code=${prodInfo.productCode}|}" th:color="white">Add to Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.product-preview-container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px ;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    color: white;
}
  
.product-preview-container input {
    width: 50px;
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Product Code, Product Name and product Price  all are coming in white. Except the `Add to Cart` potion.
My background has an image of blue color. I want to make the link `Add to Cart` to be displayed in white. How to do that ?

Comment: It requires more code than this. Do you have a minimal example so that I can see the output live?

Comment: @m4n0 : Updated the relevant section and css. Please check.

Comment: `.product-preview-container a{color: white;}` try this :)

Comment: You need a  more specific rule for the `<a>` in the container. Inspect the element styles in browser dev tools element inspector and you will see what rules currently appy to it

Comment: @RayeesAC : It worked ! Thanks Mate. Please submit ur answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply,

You can add a **color** to `<a>` tag.

```
.product-preview-container a{
  color: white;
}
```

```css
.product-preview-container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px ;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    color: white;
}
  
.product-preview-container input {
    width: 250px;
}
.bgblue{
    background:#034d89;
    width: 282px;
    /* inner div width+margin+padding+border = 250+1*10+2*5+2*1=282px */
}
.product-preview-container a{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgblue">
  <div class="product-preview-container" th:each="prodInfo : ${products}">
      <ul>
          <li>Product Code:  <span th:utext="${prodInfo.productCode}"></span></li>
          <li>Product Name:  <span th:utext="${prodInfo.productName}"></span></li>
          <li>Product Price: Rs <span th:utext="${prodInfo.productPrice}"></span></li>
          <li><a th:href="@{|/shopping/buyProduct?code=${prodInfo.productCode}|}" th:color="white">Add to Cart</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```